# Adjust Element Size In Collection View Cell Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I've been trying to adjust the size of an image view in a collection view cell programmatically, I've tried...

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,77,77)
}
```

Which didn't affect the image view at all. I also tried adding constraints programatically...

```
// Height constraint

imageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 77))

// Width constraint

imageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 77))
```

I tried adding these constraints to both the awakeFromNib and in the cellForItem function which again didn't affect the image view at all. Please tell me if any more information is needed. Thank you!

Comment: Note that it is bad practice to use `addConstraint`. Use the `active` property or `activateConstraints:` instead.

Comment: @TroyT How would I do this in my case?

Comment: Instead of calling `addConstraint`, you would assign the constraint to a constant and then set the `active` property on the constraint to `true`.

Comment: @TroyT Could you make that an answer so I can try it out and accept it?

Comment: Are you trying to use a nib in a collection view? is the nib file has only the image view? post the nib view.

Comment: @JIthinIk I'm not doing this in a nib view I'm doing this in main storyboard.

Comment: Well, it's probably not the answer to your question, I was just noting that you shouldn't use `addConstraint`.